# spring integration - read file from FTP and process it. How can we achieve metastore and process it without polling

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

In spring integration - Im trying to read file from FTP and process it. How can we achieve metastore and process it without polling.
In the below configuration, in order to avoid reading the same file, if server restart happen ,I have introduced message-store in the ftpChannel.
Now, the processor of the file is service activator, which needs polling. How can i avoid polling in service activator and read the file from ftpChannel queue immediately. If i use int:dispatcher then, I couldnot use message-store.

How can we resolve this?

```
<int:channel id="ftpChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="mongoDbMessageStore" />
    <!-- <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/> -->
</int:channel>

<bean id="mongoDbMessageStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="collectionName" value="ftpInfo" />
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel" session-factory="ftpClientFactory" charset="UTF-8"
    auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
    filename-pattern="*.gz" remote-directory="/myfilerepo/#{istDate.getISTDate()}"
    remote-file-separator="/" local-filename-generator-expression="#this.toUpperCase()"
    temporary-file-suffix=".writing" preserve-timestamp="true"
    local-directory="/temp/spring/#{istDate.getISTDate()}">

     <int:poller cron="0-5 0/5 * * * ?" max-messages-per-poll="-1"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator id="jobServiceActivator"
    input-channel="ftpChannel" ref="triggerJobLauncher" method="launch">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10" />
</int:service-activator>

<!-- job context -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
<!-- job context -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `message-store` on the channel; you need to use an [FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound) in the `filter` and/or a [FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html) in the `local-filter` to avoid reprocessing files after a system restart.

They need a `MetadataStore`; <s>if you want to use mongo you'll need to implement one; the framework currently doesn't have a mongo implementation.</s>

**EDIT:**

As of version 4.2, the framework [now has a mongo `MetadataStore`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html#x4.2-mongodb-metadata-store).

Comment: I m trying this technique.,

Comment: `<bean id="metadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore"/>
<bean id="acceptOnceFilter"
class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
  <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/>
  <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="test-" />
 </bean>`

Comment: Just be aware that the `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` only persists the metadata to disk on a normal application context shutdown. `System.exit(n)` or power loss will lose in-memory state. It's generally better to use some external store, such as Redis. If you decide to implement a mongo `MetadataStore`, consider [contributing it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: "PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore only persists the metadata to disk on a normal application context shutdown" or if `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.flushOnUpdate` is `true`

Comment: Thanks, yes, that property was added in [version 4.1.5](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3721).

Answer (score 0):

According to your concern `to avoid reading the same file from the QueueChannel`, I'd say that you worry that Spring Application always process the same message after application startup. But it isn't true. The message are removed from the queue (and, of course, from the `MessageStore`) when it is `polled` from there. If you `MessageStore` is transactional resource (e.g. JDBC), the record for messages is marked to remove until TX commit or rollback.
It isn't case for MongoDB though, but any message from the queue are polled only once, even if you have a cluster of such an application.

So, I don't understand why are you sure that your `<service-activator>` accepts the same file (as `payload`) because you restart the app.

From other side, if you want to access to the `MessageGroup` backed by your `ftpChannel`, you can do this:

```
mongoDbMessageStore.getMessageGroup("mongoDbMessageStore:ftpChannel");
```

From other side you always can `purge` `QueueChannel` manually, injection `ftpChannel` to some service as `QueueChannelOperations`.

Comment: I agreed the above logic, will process the message only once, but I need to poll the queue(from service activator), here the polling period is 10 ms, which is a delay to me. Do we have anyway to read queue message without polling?

Comment: `fidex-delay` is translated to the `PeriodicTrigger`, since you don't have `initialDelay` (and we don't expose it to the `<poller>`), so there won't be a delay for the first `poll` after application startup.

Comment: we are worried about the polling/periodic delay in processing the queue, instead it has to be in notification based communication.

Comment: Actually, it is OK with your `fixed-delay="10"` configuration. Since you don't use `max-messages-per-poll` the single polling task reads messages from the queue until they are there. See this for more info: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#polling-consumer